# Concurrent servlet requests overwrites static values

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, synchronization

I have deployed a simple Java web application which uses servlets. I am facing issues with concurrent requests.

Sample Program :

```
Public Class Test {
 static int num;
 public Test(){
 }
 public void setVal{
  Date dd = new Date();
  this.num = dd.getTime.toString()
 }
 public int getVal {
  return this.num;
 }
}

Public Class Print {
 Function generateID{
  Test test = new Test();
  test.setVal();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  System.out.print(test.getVal() );
 }
}
```

Let's say Request1 calls the generateID from class Print. While request 1 is sleeping for 10 secs request2 comes and calls the same function generateID. Function setVal() would overwrite the value of num. Meanwhile, request 1 prints the overwritten value of num.

How do I make these requests independent from each other and not overlap with each other.I don't want to use synchronized, as the actual program runs for more than an hour for each request, so I cannot lock the function. Also, is there any other way apart from using sessions.

Comment: Synchronization should be done only around the critical section. If your critical section is only the `val`, then that's all you need to wrap, not the whole method.

Comment: Make `num` a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis- there's only one instance of the servlet; won't synchronizing access to that variable result in a crippling bottleneck for the entire servlet?

Answer (score 0):

As `Sotirios Delimanolis` said in his comment you should lock the thread using `synchronized` keyword in java.

*Synchronized methods enable a simple strategy for preventing thread interference and memory consistency errors: if an object is visible to more than one thread, all reads or writes to that object's variables are done through synchronized methods.*

```
public void synchronized generateID{
  Test test = new Test();
  test.setVal();
  Thread.sleep(10000);
  System.out.print(test.getVal() );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **design** your application so atomic in nature operations take as little time as possible.

In your case you would create an additional **synchronized** `setGetVall()` method in your `Test` class:

```
public int synchronized setGetVal() {
    setVal();
    return getVal()
}
```

then you will have

```
public void generateID() {
  Test test = new Test();
  int final newValue = test.setGetVal();
  Thread.sleep(10000);   // and now it can safely sleep as long as it wants
  System.out.print( newValue );
}
```

With more sophisticated cases you will need [more sophisticated locking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), but the principle stays the same.

Comment: May be my question was not right. The getVal() is called from multiple places in the program for a request. However, the setVal() is just called once for a request. In that case, synchronised is unusable

Comment: Your `getVal()` is still available and does not need to be synchronized.  If your `num` is indeed concurrently shared between threads then you have to lock it in some form for the duration of the update-retrieval process (which is your example will be virtually instantaneous). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Synchronized access to an instance variable will only result in a bottleneck; multiple threads will only queue up to wait for a lock on a single variable

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at ThreadLocal which provides the privilege to create local variables within threads. Here is the link. Hopefully, this solves your problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are not meant to have instance variables that you don't want to make available between multiple threads, period. A single instance of a single servlet exists at any one time; every request to the servlet is executed in its own stack, its own thread, but there's only one instance of the servlet.

Synchronizing access to that instance variable will only provide a bottleneck in your application; don't do it.